# Caching behavior of UIImage

Tags: iphone, caching, uiimage

Does `UIImage` ever removes images from its cache? Can I keep a pointer to an image I got from `imageNamed:` and use it as long as I like or must I always call `imageNamed:`?

Answer (score 2):

The `UIImage` object that is returned from `imageNamed:` is treated like all other objects as far a memory management goes.  If you want to keep the reference to the object between method calls, you should `retain` it and `release` it when you are done to decrement the reference count.

```
UIImage * cachedImage;

-(void) getTheImage {
  UIImage * cachedImage = [[UImage imageNamed:@"MyImage.png"] retain];
  //Do something with the image...
}
//In some other method or dealloc
[cachedImage release];
```

Also, note that the [UIImage class reference](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/uikit/reference/UIImage_Class/Reference/Reference.html) says:

> In low-memory situations, image data
>   may be purged from a UIImage object to
>   free up memory on the system. **This
>   purging behavior affects only the
>   image data stored internally by the
>   UIImage object and not the object
>   itself.** When you attempt to draw an
>   image whose data has been purged, the
>   image object automatically reloads the
>   data from its original file. This
>   extra load step, however, may incur a
>   small performance penalty.

Answer (score 0):

UIImage caches the data itself. You must not hold a pointer and just pass that around. That can be unsafe since when there is a memory warning and there was no strong ref to that object then UIImage will purge cached data. Call [UIImage imageNamed:] every time. It is fast and returns the ref to the image from memory. If the image is no longer in memory it will reload it and pass that ref