# Caching images in Xcode? how?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, image, caching

I have started working on a new Xcode project, a game to be exact. Now, i will be adding what you might call sprites to the screen quite frequently, and the image that represents them will be either of a total of 3. Now, when i start adding these images programmatically to the viewcontrollers view, the app will start lagging as i reach a still fairly low number compared to many other games out there (maybe 5-10). Now, i was wondering if it had to do with caching? i see you can cache images in Cocos2d which i just started learning, to reduce the processing time of rendering the images on-screen. How do i come about this in Xcode?

IN SHORT: How do i "cache" or allow Xcode to rapidly draw images to prevent lag when drawing multiple images?

Thanks on advance.
JBJ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Xcode is the IDE and development environment, it's not the operating system, which is where any caching would really be happening.

`UIImage` *does* do some kind of caching ([here is a related question that talks about this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1486563/caching-behavior-of-uiimage)) but if you're going to be using cocos2d, you should rely more upon whatever your game framework provides versus what the O.S> provides.

Answer (score 0):

You should rely on a proper API (like cocos2d, since you are talking about it) to develop games, not on UIKit classes which are not meant to be used in this way.. why should caching be supported in something that is used for layouts and interfaces and not for realtime rendering?

Comment: That might be true, but apple do have some gameKit frameworks, so i just thought it might be possible, since i just started learning cocos2d i haven't really the skillset to develop full games in it yet, and i also gotta refresh my memory on memory management as cocos2d seemingly doesnt support ARC :( Thx anyways

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Jack that you should probably just use Cocos2D.  But if you want to do it yourself, you should use the `imageNamed:` method of `UIImage` to load the images, because it takes care of caching automatically, and you should use `UIImageView` to display the images, because Apple has put a lot of effort into optimizing `UIImageView`.